# React-Native project configuration

Tags: react-native, webpack, expo, babeljs

I have a cloned git project.

It uses "Webpack", expo, metroBundler

After I run script to web version of expo:

Starting Metro Bundler
Starting Webpack on port 19006 in development mode.

Then I get 138 errors in console, the app is on localhost but nothing is rendered on the screen.

What could be the problem? Webpack? Babel? Appreaciate the assistance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.